# Mule Transform Set Dynamic Key From Payload

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I want to set up a key value dictionary from 2 different fields in my payload. My first thought is to use a transform component and dynamically set the key, but this code does not work:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    payload.objectnumber: payload.objectid
}
```

I get this error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Invalid input "payload.", expected conditionalKeyValuePair,
   keyValuePair, enclosedExpr or objectEnd
- no viable alternative at input 'payload'
- no viable alternative at input '.'
```

Any ideas on how to get it working?

Input:

```
[{
  objectnumber: 75,
  objectid: "abcdefgh"
}]
```

Expected Output:

```
[{
  "abcdefgh": 75
}]
```

Comment: Post your input payload and expected output?

Comment: Yeah I'll add it to the question but it's pretty simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a variable inside bracket *(value)* to define a dynamic key. Therefore, you can try this code:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload map {
    ($.objectid): $.objectnumber
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
    <dw:transform-message metadata:id="b968b3ec-ed0a-492d-bf32-bcfe0d20e9d0" doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
       %output application/java
       %var objectId = payload.objectid
       ---
        objectId :payload.objectnumber
        ]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
```

JSON Input in Postman:

```
 [  
   {  
  "objectnumber":75,
  "objectid":"abcdefgh"
   }
 ]
```